# Miniconda already in PATH in VSCode Terminal but not in System Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with the PATH when using the VSCode integrated terminal. My `~/.bash_profile` contains the Conda init code to setup the PATH and aliases.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

It appears that this bit here does *not* do modify the PATH if Conda is already in it.

I added this line *at the beginning* of my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"
```

Opening the macOS Terminal, I see what I expect:

```
BEGINNING
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/go/bin

END
/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/bin
/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/condabin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/go/bin
```

But in a fresh VSCode Terminal, I see instead

```
BEGINNING
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/go/bin
/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/bin
/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/condabin
/usr/local/sbin
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
/usr/local/gnupg-2.2/bin

END
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/go/bin
/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/bin
/Users/nrosenstein/miniconda3/condabin
/usr/local/sbin
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
/usr/local/gnupg-2.2/bin
```

In VSCode, Miniconda is already in the PATH at the beginning of `~/.bash_profile`. This wouldn't be an issue if it were at the beginning of the PATH, but since it follows `/usr/bin`, `python` is always the system Python version, not the one in the Conda environment.

Why are these paths already in VSCode? How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you look in `.vscode/settings.json`?

Comment: @l'L'l Only one of projects in my Workspace had this folder due to the Python extension that I had installed (and then uninstall) which specified only a single field for the Python version. None of it indicates that it would alter my PATH. I also don't see anything that could cause this in my user settings, the osx shell and shellArgs are set to `"bash"` and `["-l"]` respectively.